# How to exec mmaped binary/code right from the allocated memory

Tags: c++, c

I have some binary, I use mmap() to write it into memory. Then i try to exec it right from the allocated memory, but till now it is no results. Can anyone help? Examples are appreciated)
I am on Ubuntu,
any binary(c hello world), its size file_size, its descriptor fd and then:

```
addr = mmap(NULL, file_size, PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, pa_offset);
           if (addr == MAP_FAILED)
               handle_error("mmap");
```

so i dont know how to exec it

Comment: You should be showing your code in the question, not just asking for examples. Do you have a page with the execute permissions? What is the code of "some binary" you're trying to run? What happens when you try to run it? Nothing, segfault? Please add considerably more details.

Comment: Is it necessary to be done like this? The normal way to start a program from another process would be to use one of the functions of the exec() family ...

Comment: If you are trying to write a program that takes "plug-ins", the C library has you covered: build the plugins as shared objects rather than executables, then use [`dlopen` and `dlsym`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) to load and call them. If you are trying to generate machine code on the fly and execute it (a "just-in-time" compiler or similar), you're probably running foul of the [W^X policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%5EX); you have to write the code into memory and then use [`mprotect`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mprotect) to make it executable. The C library won't help with that.

Comment: And if you want to write your own executable loader by hand, you need to read "[Linkers and Loaders](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1103509.Linkers_and_Loaders)."  That's an entire book, and it's only a starting point.

Comment: the `mmap()` function can only allocate memory pages with a readable and/or writable attributes, not executable attribute. So, naturally, cannot execute anything in that `mmap`d memory area

Comment: @user3629249 That's not true, `PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC` works just fine.  The dynamic linker does it all the time.  Run `strace /bin/ls` and see for yourself.  (On current-generation kernels the call will fail if you ask for *write* and execute privileges simultaneously, but that's a recently-added security restriction.)

Comment: @zwol,  Your correct about PROT_EXEC.  I have never used that particular parameter, so had forgotten about it.

Answer (score 5):

While your question remains confusing even after the edit, I think you've said enough to identify what you're doing wrong.

> any binary(c hello world)

You cannot execute a `mmap`ed binary file in the same way that the OS executes it. You're running on Linux so your hello world is likely a binary in the ELF format. Linux knows how to read and execute ELF binaries, your program doesn't. The ELF [starts with a header](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) and so your memory-mapped data also starts with the header. Which is not executable code. The header starts with `0x7F`, which corresponds to the `jg` instruction on x86, so attempting to 'execute' an ELF header as executable code would possibly (depending on the status of your flags) immediately jump to a garbage address built up of the next bytes of the header.

If you want to run code like this, you'll need to parse the ELF file, find its entry point (or, likely, the `.init` section first) and start executing code from there. You should certainly feel free to do this as an exercise, for learning purposes, but that is not the normal way of executing another program from your own. A typical approach would be to use the `fork` and `exec` calls instead. That lets Linux handle the technicalities of launching the program.

Comment: Does that actually work? I've never tried but my guess would be it would die at the first relocation (which may be needed well before even calling `main()`).

Comment: @TheVee It would be necessary to do all of the work normally done by `ld.so`, yes.

Comment: @TheVee It will probably succeed on something as simple as a statically-linked Hello World. In general, it's going to segfault very soon though.

Answer (score 2):

It's next to impossible to exec into an arbitrary memory image.
ELF files must be mmaped in a particular way in the process address space, almost never as a contiguous image of the underlying file.

The closest workable approach I can think of is saving the image into a (possibly nameless) file and exec'ing that file via `execveat(fd, "", ...)`. Check execveat(2) around where they talk about empty pathname, and open(2) on O_TMPFILE.

A named temp file and a regular execve(2) would work as well, as long as the gap between close/munmap and execve when the file may be changed is not an issue.

Another idea would be to do ELF loading completely in userspace, setting up the proper address space for the new process, calling LD and such. Definitely not easy. Does not require any execve(2) call, just fork and work from there. Because execve(2) won't be used, certain things like O_CLOEXEC handling and un-mmaping extra memory will require non-trivial workarounds.